# Effective potential for Kerr incorrect?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, kerr-metric

I am self-learning GR.

**Background**

I have been following [Christopher Hirata's lecture notes on Kerr geodesics](http://www.tapir.caltech.edu/~chirata/ph236/2011-12/lec26.pdf). In Equation 38, the effective potential $V(r)$ is given by:

$V(r)=(1-\epsilon)^2r^4-2Mr^3+(a^2(1-\epsilon^2)+L^2+Q)r^2-2M((a\epsilon-L)^2+Q)r+a^2Q$,

where $\epsilon$ is particle's energy per unit mass, $L$ is angular momentum per unit mass, $Q$ is the Carter's constant, $r$ is the radius (Boyer-Lindquist coordinates), $a$ is the black hole's spin, $M$ is the mass of the black hole.

The lecture notes then goes on to say:

> Here V (r) is a fourth-order polynomial in r; the particle is trapped in the regions where it is negative

And in the [next lecture](http://www.tapir.caltech.edu/~chirata/ph236/2011-12/lec27.pdf), it is stated that:

> and the particle bounces back and forth between two zeroes of this potential (it is trapped in regions where V is
>   negative)

**The problem**

I have made a code for calculating the roots of $V(r)=0$ for a given particle, which should give the minimum and maximum encounter with the black hole. Yet, when I plot the particle geodesics the answer is not consistent:

[image]

The numerical geodesics fluctuate around $2.2 R_s$ to $5.9 R_s$, whereas the roots of the potential are [8.9486e-12, 0.6749, 0.83789, 222.877]$R_s$

*Some additional info as requested*: Particle initial value: $[t,r,\theta,\phi,u^t,u^r,u^\theta,u^\phi]$ =[0,11.791,1.5708,0,1.12008,0,0,0.0186647] with $M=1$ and $a=0.995$

**Question**

Do the $V(r)=0$ roots give the minimum and maximum encounter of stable orbits with the black hole?

Comment: Could you maybe add some important snippets of your code too?

Comment: @Eh-whaaa I added the particle initial values and black hole mass and spin for reference :)

I completed the effective potential root finding in both c++ with Jenkins-Traub algorithm and in Mathematica, both giving the same result. The particle trajectories are calculated with the open source GYOTO software.

Comment: I'll re-check the effective potential with the one introduced here: http://universeinproblems.com/index.php/Kerr_black_hole#Particles.27_motion_in_the_equatorial_plane

Comment: It seems the effective potential in the notes is incorrect. Or maybe I am interpreting it incorrectly. I used the effective potential in the universe in problems and it seems to give the correct answer.